# jquery ui and simpledialog2 problems

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery ui (datapicker) and trying simpledialog2 http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html

If I include reference to jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js the simpledialog2 doesn't work.  I can comment out a reference to jquery-ui and things work great.

The problem, when jquery-ui is referenced (and it seems regardless of order of references) when I click a button to open the dialog a larger gray dialog opens first covering the simpledialog2 window.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can use please add in what order are you importing those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using jquery-ui with jquery mobile the problem is more than likely in the order of your referencing of the js libraries.  I have found this to be the solution to my jqm and jquery-ui incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that after I did this

```
<script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.js"></script>
```

jQuery-UI's build-in dialog function failed to work.
It is likely jQuery-UI and jQuery Mobile can't fit each other. Actually jQuery Mobile is designed for lightweight usages like mobile phones. But jQuery-UI is more likely designed for desktop web apps.